# Developing a system-wide keyboard for Tizen

Tags: tizen

I'm looking into developing a keyboard on the Tizen OS that would be available for all applications requiring input, similar to what is available on Android and soon iOS 8.

I looked into the issue and there seems to be mixed results. [This wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mobile_operating_systems) says neither yes nor no to the functionality. This [email correspondence](https://lists.tizen.org/pipermail/application-dev/2012-September/000252.html) says that they [Tizen] weren't sure whether or not to open up the input API because of key loggers. However, that was for 1.0, not 2.0.

I need to know whether this functionality is available and, if so, how to approach it. Would it be written in C or could it be written as a web app in HTML/CSS/JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the IME (Input Method Editor) API?

- [Tizen::Ui::Ime Namespace Reference](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.apireference/namespaceTizen_1_1Ui_1_1Ime.html) (API since Tizen 2.1, the description is for 2.2.1)
- [Sample IME](https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/articles/sample-ime)

Comment: Hi, this is old but isthere any chance you are able to update your first link ?